# Simple Flash form, redirecting to URL using textfield as argument

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

This seemed simple enough, I do know Java, PHP and JavaScript, so it's simply a matter of not enough knowledge of the Flash/ActionScript 3.0 platform.

After doing some research, I added a layer to the movie for the code (Flash CS5). I then right-click, select "Actions" and write this code.

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, setup);

submitButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onSubmit);
queryField.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onQueryClick);

var defaultText = "Search...";

function setup(){
    queryField.text = defaultText;
}
function onSubmit(){
    if(queryField.text != defaultText && queryField.text != ""){
        navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.somedomain.com/?query=" + queryField.text), "_blank");
    }
}
function onQueryClick(){ 
    if(queryField.text == defaultText){
        queryField.text = "";
    }
}
```

As you can see, I want to add a default text on load to the form field referenced by "queryField", which should clear on focusing the field. When submitting the form the browser should redirect to an URL appending the value of queryField.

As I said, I don't have enough knowledge of the platform to know what's wrong. Although it seems like maybe the references in the functions are not available due to the different scope. But a different example I saw ignored scope of form field references as well.

Right now, the published movies does precisely nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to set a default value to the `TextField`, there is no need to use an `ENTER_FRAME` event. Just do that :

```
var defaultText = "Search...";
queryField.text = defaultText;
```

In your code, the `TextField` is continously updated with the default value (see the `ENTER_FRAME` event [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#event%3aenterFrame)). That's why nothing happend, the `TextField` is always equal to the default text.

Comment: Originally I just did it in the scope outside the functions, but that reverted the value to defaultText every time the last frame played.
Edit: to clarify: nothing happens, not even setting the default text. As I say: PRECISELY nothing.

Comment: Is your MovieClip added to the main stage ?

Comment: I don't think it was originally. But the whole document contains only one layer and the top left corner says just "Scene 1". Still nothing is happening though.

Comment: It would be more easy if you provide a link to your .fla (export cs4)

Comment: Agreed: http://rapidshare.com/files/444956136/test.fla

Thank you very much for your help, I'm not getting very far and I really think the issue is with the movie, not the script.

Comment: When i compile your .fla i get a compile time error (ComponentShim)... Also, you have multiples frames in your scene. Just keep only one frame (the first one with the code). This will solve your textfield reset problem.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm still not sure what I did wrong, but I bet I'll find out when trying to apply this to the actual movie.

Any idea how to fix the notification I get at the point it should redirect? I ran the movie in IE and instead of redirecting it prompts to modify settings :S

Comment: Never mind, it only complains on local html files. Thank you for your help :)